# How to call a SERVICE inside a Merge Scan when using the Reactive Approach RXJS in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am trying to use the reactive approach in my angular app and I am having trouble calling a service inside a scan. How do I do this? It seems the service returns an observable - how do I deal with this?    Here is the error that I see: *Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'SomeItemModel'.*

```
itemsWithAdditions$ = merge(this.items$, this.saveItemAction$).pipe(
scan((acc, value) => {
  //Check if an array
  if (value instanceof Array) {

    return this.someService.someMethod(res).pipe(map(res => {
      value.forEach(item => {
        item.price = res.find(x => x.id === item.id).map(x => x.price);
      })
        
    }))
  }
  // Otherwise, add that value to the array
  else {
    acc.push(value);
    return acc;
  }
}, [] as SomeItemModel[] // this is the initial value for the array
)
```

);

Comment: I think you are returning `Observable` inside scan operator and this is not allowed. You need `mergeScan` operator not scan.

Comment: you are right @GRD. The code sample above is just a simple representation of what I am trying to do - but in my actual code  I am trying to use this merge scan to "conditionally" call different services - depending on the stream that emits. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: May be you can use `partition` operator first to get two different values based on your condition and then next stream you can do rest. But I do not know how to do it at present.

Comment: Which version of rxjs are you running ?  Why does your map doesn't return anything ?  Please provide an example with you error on https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I your case, you need to use `mergeScan` if you want to return an observable in a `scan`.
This means, any returned value must be an observable :

```
itemsWithAdditions$ = merge(this.items$, this.saveItemAction$).pipe(
  mergeScan(
    (acc, value) => {
      if (value instanceof Array) {
        return this.someService.someMethod(res).pipe( // observable here 
          map((res) => {
            // don't forget to return a value here
            value.forEach((item) => {
              item.price = res
                .find((x) => x.id === item.id)
                .map((x) => x.price);
            });
          })
        );
      }
      else {
        acc.push(value);
        return of(acc); // observable here
      }
    },
    [] as SomeItemModel[] 
  )
);
```

NB: Don't forget to return a value in a `map()`.